# How to prevent some background-images caching

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image, no-cache

adding some random number it works, but only for img

```
<img src="example.jpg?377489229" />
```

Is there any way to prevent caching prp. `background-image`?

```
<div style="background-image: url(example.jpg  )"></div>"
```

Answer (score 5):

The same technique will work there.

```
<div style="background-image: url(example.jpg?377489229)"></div>
```

Assuming your server doesn't act differently with the presence of that GET param.

This will only break the cache once though, if you want it to always hit the server, you will need to use some different techniques.

Comment: i have no idea... can you give me some links to learn more about it

Answer (score 2):

To generate image urls with dynamic timestamp as query param You need at least JavaScript code that will dynamically add latest timestamp to background image url and make something like this:

```
someimage.jpg? (new Date()).getTime()    =>   someimage.jpg?1479341018085
```

You can use this example:

```js
function getNoCacheBgElements() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.no-cache-bg');
}

function loadBgImageForElement(element) {
  element.style['background-image'] = 
    'url('+ element.attributes['data-background-image'].value + '?' + (new Date()).getTime() +')';
}

function loadBgImages() {
  for(
    var i = 0, elements = getNoCacheBgElements();
    i < elements.length;
    loadBgImageForElement(elements[i]), i++ 
  );
}

window.onload = function() {
  loadBgImages();
};
```

```css
.size-100x100 {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
   
.float-left {float: left;}
.margin-10 {margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<p> These background images loaded dynamically every time You hit "Run code snippet". </p>

<div class="no-cache-bg size-100x100 float-left margin-10" data-background-image="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-8.jpg"></div>

<div class="no-cache-bg size-100x100 float-left margin-10" data-background-image="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-9.jpg"></div>

<div class="no-cache-bg size-100x100 float-left margin-10" data-background-image="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-10.jpg"></div>
 
</br>
<p> Check browser's network tab and You'll see that it requests for images on every page load. </p>
```